# How Can I set the right flag according to row status

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to flag packages that weren't collected by customers for each relay point.

To identify a left package (not collected by customer) the status need to be ("**Dropoff**" or "**preparation**")

Requirements :

| Flag Cases | Example |
| --- | --- |
| The row needs to be the first row with status ID in (20,71) | Rows 7,34 |
| The row needs to be the first row with status ID in (20,71) Following a row with status in (50,51,90,91,30,60,10) | Rows 3,10,27.. |

The expected result :

| Line Number | OrderNumber | RelayPoint | Status | DateShipper | F | ID Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | XN75 | NULL | Shipment | 1/27/2022 15:29 | 0 | 10 |
| 3 | XN75 | 123 | Dropoff | 2/1/2022 7:15 | 1 | 20 |
| 4 | XN75 | 123 | Relay point Collection | 2/2/2022 7:50 | 0 | 90 |
| 5 | XN75 | 123 | Collected | 2/2/2022 7:50 | 0 | 91 |
| 6 | XN75 | 45678 | Shipper | 2/2/2022 16:02 | 0 | 30 |
| 7 | XN76 | 234 | Dropoff | 4/1/2022 9:16 | 1 | 20 |
| 8 | XN76 | 234 | Dropoff | 4/1/2022 9:17 | 0 | 20 |
| 9 | XN77 | 980 | Shipper Delivery | 9/22/2022 9:23 | 0 | 50 |
| 10 | XN77 | 980 | Preparation | 9/29/2022 23:00 | 1 | 71 |
| 11 | XN77 | 980 | Shipper Delivery | 10/1/2022 10:48 | 0 | 50 |
| 12 | XN77 | 980 | Preparation | 10/11/2022 16:48 | 1 | 71 |
| 13 | XN81 | 1314 | Dropoff | 10/10/2022 13:45 | 1 | 20 |
| 14 | XN81 | 1314 | Relay point Delivery | 10/11/2022 13:46 | 0 | 51 |
| 15 | XN81 | 1314 | Preparation | 10/11/2022 15:45 | 1 | 71 |
| 16 | XN81 | 1314 | Pickup | 10/12/2022 8:46 | 0 | 60 |
| 17 | XN79 | NULL | Shipment | 9/25/2022 20:38 | 0 | 10 |
| 18 | XN79 | 979 | Dropoff | 10/1/2022 9:16 | 1 | 20 |
| 19 | XN79 | 979 | Relay point Collection | 10/3/2022 10:14 | 0 | 90 |
| 20 | XN79 | 198271 | Shipper | 10/4/2022 15:05 | 0 | 30 |
| 21 | XN79 | 154 | Shipper Delivery | 10/9/2022 10:42 | 0 | 50 |
| 22 | XN79 | 154 | Relay point Delivery | 10/9/2022 10:43 | 0 | 51 |
| 23 | XN79 | 154 | Pickup | 10/9/2022 14:08 | 0 | 60 |
| 24 | XN79 | 711 | Dropoff | 10/10/2022 13:45 | 1 | 20 |
| 25 | XN79 | 108223 | Shipper | 10/11/2022 13:45 | 0 | 30 |
| 26 | XN80 | 980 | Shipper Delivery | 9/22/2022 9:23 | 0 | 50 |
| 27 | XN80 | 980 | Preparation | 9/29/2022 23:00 | 1 | 71 |
| 28 | XN80 | 980 | Shipper Delivery | 10/1/2022 10:48 | 0 | 50 |
| 29 | XN80 | 980 | Preparation | 10/11/2022 16:48 | 1 | 71 |
| 30 | XN80 | 980 | Shipper Delivery | 10/12/2022 10:48 | 0 | 50 |
| 31 | XN80 | 980 | Preparation | 10/13/2022 16:48 | 1 | 71 |
| 32 | XD30 | 340 | Dropoff | 11/17/2022 12:29 | 1 | 20 |
| 33 | XD30 | 340 | Pickup | 11/17/2022 12:48 | 0 | 60 |
| 34 | XD30 | 340 | Dropoff | 11/20/2022 18:24 | 1 | 20 |
| 35 | XD30 | 340 | Preparation | 11/20/2022 18:25 | 0 | 71 |
| 36 | XD30 | 340 | Collected | 11/20/2022 18:26 | 0 | 91 |

I tried the query as below but it doesn't give the right result.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,Row_number() OVER (partition BY ordernumber, relaypoint ORDER BY dateshipper) AS RN
         FROM   #shipperstatushistory t1
         WHERE  status IN( 'Dropoff', 'preparation' )
                AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                            FROM   #shipperstatushistory t2
                            WHERE  status IN( 'shipper Delivery','Relay point Delivery','pickup','announcement','Shipment', 'collected', 'shipper','Relay point Collection')
                                   AND t1.ordernumber = t2.ordernumber
                                   AND t1.relaypoint = t2.relaypoint
                                   AND t2.dateshipper > t1.dateshipper)
         UNION
         SELECT*,Row_number() OVER (partition BY ordernumber, relaypoint ORDER BY dateshipper) AS RN
         FROM   #shipperstatushistory t1
         WHERE  status IN( 'Dropoff', 'preparation' )
                AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                FROM   #shipperstatushistory t2
                                WHERE  status IN( 'shipper Delivery','Relay point Delivery','pickup','announcement','Shipment', 'collected', 'shipper','Relay point Collection')
                                       AND t1.ordernumber = t2.ordernumber
                                       AND t1.relaypoint = t2.relaypoint
                                       AND t2.dateshipper > t1.dateshipper))
SELECT t.*,
       CASE WHEN t2.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS f
FROM   #shipperstatushistory t
       LEFT JOIN cte t2
              ON t.id = t2.id
                 AND rn = 1
```

My query returns wrong values on OrderNumber XN81 and XN80 and XD30

[**Here is a sqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/76d0aa)

Thanks for help !

Comment: Your example data in the fiddle doesn't provide a StatusID number, just a Status column which contains a string. Can you map those?

Comment: @PatrickHurst I think you can just use the `IN` clauses the OP has. e.g. "dropoff" and "preparation" are 20 and 71 respectively, and the longer list are the other ones. That's the assumption I'm working off of. And it does seem to match up with the markdown table

Comment: Sure, that works for the first two, but there is a long list of constraints for the second criteria.

Comment: Those are the items: `IN( 'shipper Delivery','Relay point Delivery','pickup','announcement','Shipment', 'collected', 'shipper','Relay point Collection')`

Comment: @MR_King, I have a solution which works by adding a `Flag` field to your temp table, and progressively updating it. From there, you could then select from the updated temp table, which would have the flag set correctly. Will that suffice? Or do you want a single query which will output the results?

Comment: @Xedni you have 8 items in your `IN` there are only 7 StatusIDs.

Comment: K, I don't know then. Maybe typo in the OP?

Comment: @Xedni I prefer a single query if it's possible . I tried also another query but i have some issue :(

Comment: **This question is a repost.** The original question, along with discussions and a (since deleted) proposed solution, can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77608452/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
DECLARE @ShipperStatusHistory TABLE (id Int primary key identity, OrderNumber varchar(50), RelayPoint INT, Status varchar(50), DateShipper Datetime);
    
INSERT INTO @ShipperStatusHistory VALUES 
('XN75',NULL,'Shipment','2022-01-27 15:29:22.000'), ('XN75',123,'Dropoff','2022-02-01 07:15:53.000'), ('XN75',123,'Relay point Collection','2022-02-02 07:50:29.000'),
('XN75',123,'collected','2022-02-02 07:50:45.000'), ('XN75',45678,'shipper','2022-02-02 16:02:37.000'), ('XN76',234,'Dropoff','2022-04-01 09:16:51.000'),
('XN76',234,'Dropoff','2022-04-01 09:17:06.000'), ('XN77',980,'shipper Delivery','2022-09-22 09:23:35.000'), ('XN77',980,'Preparation','2022-09-29 23:00:06.000'),
('XN77',980,'shipper Delivery','2022-10-01 10:48:04.000'), ('XN77',980,'Preparation','2022-10-11 16:48:30.000'), ('XN81',1314,'Dropoff','2022-10-10 13:45:59.000'),
('XN81',1314,'Relay point Delivery','2022-10-11 13:46:59.000'), ('XN81',1314,'Preparation','2022-10-11 15:45:59.000'), ('XN81',1314,'Pickup','2022-10-12 08:46:59.000'),
('XN79',NULL,'Shipment','2022-09-25 20:38:19.000'), ('XN79',979,'Dropoff','2022-10-01 09:16:51.000'), ('XN79',979,'Relay point Collection','2022-10-03 10:14:06.000'),
('XN79',198271,'shipper','2022-10-04 15:05:30.000'), ('XN79',154,'shipper Delivery','2022-10-09 10:42:01.000'), ('XN79',154,'Relay point Delivery','2022-10-09 10:43:46.000'),
('XN79',154,'Pickup','2022-10-09 14:08:50.000'), ('XN79',711,'Dropoff','2022-10-10 13:45:59.000'), ('XN79',108223,'shipper','2022-10-11 13:45:59.000'),
('XN80',980,'shipper Delivery','2022-09-22 09:23:35.000'), ('XN80',980,'Preparation','2022-09-29 23:00:06.000'), ('XN80',980,'shipper Delivery','2022-10-01 10:48:04.000'),
('XN80',980,'Preparation','2022-10-11 16:48:30.000'), ('XN80',980,'shipper Delivery','2022-10-12 10:48:04.000'), ('XN80',980,'Preparation','2022-10-13 16:48:30.000'),
('XD30',340,'Dropoff','2022-11-17 12:29:29.000'), ('XD30',340,'Pickup','2022-11-17 12:48:43.000'), ('XD30',340,'Dropoff','2022-11-20 18:24:01.000'), ('XD30',340,'Preparation','2022-11-20 18:25:12.000'),
('XD30',340,'Collected','2022-11-20 18:26:10.000');

DECLARE @Expected TABLE (LineNumber INT, OrderNumber VARCHAR(4), RelayPoint VARCHAR(20), Status VARCHAR(50), DateShipper DATETIME, F BIT, IDStatus INT);
INSERT INTO @Expected (LineNumber, OrderNumber, RelayPoint, Status, DateShipper, F, IDStatus) VALUES
(2 ,'XN75', NULL , 'Shipment ', '1/27/2022 15:29 ', 0 , 10), (3 ,'XN75', 123 , 'Dropoff', '2/1/2022 7:15 ', 1 , 20), (4 ,'XN75', 123 , 'Relay point Collection ', '2/2/2022 7:50 ', 0 , 90),
(5 ,'XN75', 123 , 'Collected ', '2/2/2022 7:50 ', 0 , 91), (6 ,'XN75', 45678 , 'Shipper', '2/2/2022 16:02 ', 0 , 30), (7 ,'XN76', 234 , 'Dropoff ', '4/1/2022 9:16 ', 1 , 20), 
(8 ,'XN76', 234 , 'Dropoff ', '4/1/2022 9:17 ', 0 , 20), (9 ,'XN77', 980 , 'Shipper Delivery ', '9/22/2022 9:23 ', 0 , 50), (10 ,'XN77', 980 , 'Preparation ', '9/29/2022 23:00 ', 1 , 71), 
(11 ,'XN77', 980 , 'Shipper Delivery ', '10/1/2022 10:48 ', 0 , 50), (12 ,'XN77', 980 , 'Preparation ', '10/11/2022 16:48 ', 1 , 71), (13 ,'XN81', 1314 , 'Dropoff ', '10/10/2022 13:45 ', 1 , 20), 
(14 ,'XN81', 1314 , 'Relay point Delivery ', '10/11/2022 13:46 ', 0 , 51), (15 ,'XN81', 1314 , 'Preparation ', '10/11/2022 15:45 ', 1 , 71), (16 ,'XN81', 1314 , 'Pickup ', '10/12/2022 8:46 ', 0 , 60), 
(17 ,'XN79', NULL , 'Shipment ', '9/25/2022 20:38 ', 0 , 10), (18 ,'XN79', 979 , 'Dropoff ', '10/1/2022 9:16 ', 1 , 20), (19 ,'XN79', 979 , 'Relay point Collection ', '10/3/2022 10:14 ', 0 , 90), 
(20 ,'XN79', 198271 , 'Shipper ', '10/4/2022 15:05 ', 0 , 30), (21 ,'XN79', 154 , 'Shipper Delivery ', '10/9/2022 10:42 ', 0 , 50), (22 ,'XN79', 154 , 'Relay point Delivery ', '10/9/2022 10:43 ', 0 , 51), 
(23 ,'XN79', 154 , 'Pickup ', '10/9/2022 14:08 ', 0 , 60), (24 ,'XN79', 711 , 'Dropoff ', '10/10/2022 13:45 ', 1 , 20), (25 ,'XN79', 108223 , 'Shipper ', '10/11/2022 13:45 ', 0 , 30), 
(26 ,'XN80', 980 , 'Shipper Delivery ', '9/22/2022 9:23 ', 0 , 50), (27 ,'XN80', 980 , 'Preparation ', '9/29/2022 23:00 ', 1 , 71), (28 ,'XN80', 980 , 'Shipper Delivery ', '10/1/2022 10:48 ', 0 , 50), 
(29 ,'XN80', 980 , 'Preparation ', '10/11/2022 16:48 ', 1 , 71), (30 ,'XN80', 980 , 'Shipper Delivery ', '10/12/2022 10:48 ', 0 , 50), (31 ,'XN80', 980 , 'Preparation ', '10/13/2022 16:48 ', 1 , 71), 
(32 ,'XD30', 340 , 'Dropoff ', '11/17/2022 12:29 ', 1 , 20), (33 ,'XD30', 340 , 'Pickup ', '11/17/2022 12:48 ', 0 , 60), (34 ,'XD30', 340 , 'Dropoff ', '11/20/2022 18:24 ', 1 , 20), 
(35 ,'XD30', 340 , 'Preparation ', '11/20/2022 18:25 ', 0 , 71), (36 ,'XD30', 340 , 'Collected ', '11/20/2022 18:26 ', 0 , 91);

UPDATE @Expected SET LineNumber = LineNumber - 1;

SELECT s.*,
       CASE WHEN s.Status IN ('Dropoff','Preparation') AND ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.OrderNumber, CASE WHEN s.Status IN ('Dropoff','Preparation') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ORDER BY s.DateShipper) =  1 THEN 1
            WHEN LAG(s.Status,1) OVER (PARTITION BY s.OrderNumber ORDER BY s.DateShipper) IN ('shipper Delivery', 'Relay point Delivery', 'Pickup', 'announcement', 
                                                                                              'Shipment', 'collected', 'shipper', 'Relay point Collection') 
                 AND s.Status IN ('Dropoff','Preparation') THEN 1 
            ELSE 0
       END AS Flag, e.F
  FROM @ShipperStatusHistory s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @Expected e 
      ON s.id = e.LineNumber
 ORDER BY s.Id;
```

I've included your expected output as a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for comparison purposes. We didn't know which IDs you intended for the second criteria, so all 8 are in there, but you can easily adjust that.

| id | OrderNumber | RelayPoint | Status | DateShipper | Flag | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | XN75 |  | Shipment | 2022-01-27 15:29:22.000 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | XN75 | 123 | Dropoff | 2022-02-01 07:15:53.000 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | XN75 | 123 | Relay point Collection | 2022-02-02 07:50:29.000 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | XN75 | 123 | collected | 2022-02-02 07:50:45.000 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | XN75 | 45678 | shipper | 2022-02-02 16:02:37.000 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | XN76 | 234 | Dropoff | 2022-04-01 09:16:51.000 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | XN76 | 234 | Dropoff | 2022-04-01 09:17:06.000 | 0 | 0 |
| 8 | XN77 | 980 | shipper Delivery | 2022-09-22 09:23:35.000 | 0 | 0 |
| 9 | XN77 | 980 | Preparation | 2022-09-29 23:00:06.000 | 1 | 1 |
| 10 | XN77 | 980 | shipper Delivery | 2022-10-01 10:48:04.000 | 0 | 0 |
| 11 | XN77 | 980 | Preparation | 2022-10-11 16:48:30.000 | 1 | 1 |
| 12 | XN81 | 1314 | Dropoff | 2022-10-10 13:45:59.000 | 1 | 1 |
| 13 | XN81 | 1314 | Relay point Delivery | 2022-10-11 13:46:59.000 | 0 | 0 |
| 14 | XN81 | 1314 | Preparation | 2022-10-11 15:45:59.000 | 1 | 1 |
| 15 | XN81 | 1314 | Pickup | 2022-10-12 08:46:59.000 | 0 | 0 |
| 16 | XN79 |  | Shipment | 2022-09-25 20:38:19.000 | 0 | 0 |
| 17 | XN79 | 979 | Dropoff | 2022-10-01 09:16:51.000 | 1 | 1 |
| 18 | XN79 | 979 | Relay point Collection | 2022-10-03 10:14:06.000 | 0 | 0 |
| 19 | XN79 | 198271 | shipper | 2022-10-04 15:05:30.000 | 0 | 0 |
| 20 | XN79 | 154 | shipper Delivery | 2022-10-09 10:42:01.000 | 0 | 0 |
| 21 | XN79 | 154 | Relay point Delivery | 2022-10-09 10:43:46.000 | 0 | 0 |
| 22 | XN79 | 154 | Pickup | 2022-10-09 14:08:50.000 | 0 | 0 |
| 23 | XN79 | 711 | Dropoff | 2022-10-10 13:45:59.000 | 1 | 1 |
| 24 | XN79 | 108223 | shipper | 2022-10-11 13:45:59.000 | 0 | 0 |
| 25 | XN80 | 980 | shipper Delivery | 2022-09-22 09:23:35.000 | 0 | 0 |
| 26 | XN80 | 980 | Preparation | 2022-09-29 23:00:06.000 | 1 | 1 |
| 27 | XN80 | 980 | shipper Delivery | 2022-10-01 10:48:04.000 | 0 | 0 |
| 28 | XN80 | 980 | Preparation | 2022-10-11 16:48:30.000 | 1 | 1 |
| 29 | XN80 | 980 | shipper Delivery | 2022-10-12 10:48:04.000 | 0 | 0 |
| 30 | XN80 | 980 | Preparation | 2022-10-13 16:48:30.000 | 1 | 1 |
| 31 | XD30 | 340 | Dropoff | 2022-11-17 12:29:29.000 | 1 | 1 |
| 32 | XD30 | 340 | Pickup | 2022-11-17 12:48:43.000 | 0 | 0 |
| 33 | XD30 | 340 | Dropoff | 2022-11-20 18:24:01.000 | 1 | 1 |
| 34 | XD30 | 340 | Preparation | 2022-11-20 18:25:12.000 | 0 | 0 |
| 35 | XD30 | 340 | Collected | 2022-11-20 18:26:10.000 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: Nice. That's about what I was working towards as well.

Comment: This might be simplified farther. As I reverse engineer the solution, a row is flagged if the status is X and either (1) the row is the first X in the group or (2) the row is preceded by a not-X row. Since a row satisfying (1) either the first overall row in the group or also satisfies (2), that condition can be replaced with (1) the row is the first overall, which also is equivalent to LAG(Status) IS NULL. By adding a default value for LAG(), the test can be reduced to `s.Status IN (X) AND ISNULL(LAG(s.Status, 1, '') OVER (...) NOT IN (X)`. See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FIiRdbaU).